# Image path in node express with connect-assets

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, less, assets

I'm trying to include twitter-bootstrap in [my project](https://github.com/zishe/angular-express-coffee) and `glyphicons-halflings` images work only in the same directory (`assets/css/`) and only in Chrome (not in Firefox and Opera). Including part (file 'app.less'):

```
@import 'twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap';
@iconSpritePath: "/img/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath: "/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

I tried to use a variety of options: /img.. , img/.. , /../img , /gly..., place in a public dir (I want to use it from images folder by the way), but it's not working. Perhaps I could set this option in connect-assets. [This](http://clip2net.com/s/2bj3P) folders picture.

Including to project only app.less file `!= css('app')`

In this case it works for Chrome.

UPDATE:

Now I see that in Chrome url is always `http://localhost:3000/css/../img/glyphicons-halflings.png` that transform to `http://localhost:3000/img/glyphicons-halflings.png` and in firefox it's always `../img/glyphicons-halflings.png` (`background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");`) that unable to load. My defenition of @iconSpritePath doesn't work at all.

Comment: You have to define the variables before including bootstrap main less file. And can't you define a relative path instead ?

Comment: I change define variables. About reletive path - I have twitter bootstrap folder wich contains .less files and images too. But when I define `@iconSpritePath: "glyphicons-halflings.png"` it's not woking, so I think image should be visible by http request like `http://localhost:3000/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png` but it's not for all browsers besides Chrome.

Comment: And in Chrome it's not working now because of routes for angular: `app.get '*',  (req, res) ->
  res.render "index"`

Comment: Use the web inspector to see exactly which path is used in the generated css. Then access directly the image to see which path it should be. Finally adapt the generated path to correspond to the real one. If you can't, put the information of each step here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using bootstrap(using the LESS files) with express. works in every browser. you have to install less-middleware and less moduel. here's my code:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public' )));
```

and my folder structure:

```
/public/img <-- the bootstrap img and the rest
/public/javascripts
/public/stylesheets
```

the only thing i did have to change was the includes in the bootstrap less files.
e.g. from:

```
// CSS Reset
@import "reset.less";
```

to

```
// CSS Reset
@import "/public/stylesheets/reset.less";
```

Comment: now I'm using less too, so thanks for advise about including.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code, and simply copied the glyphicon files into the public/img folder tree and it's working for me.

I don't see any mention in https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets about it being able to support images, so I assume this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but it was unrelated to paths in css files. I was just trying to reference an image in 'assets/images' but when i used `assetPath('images/logo.png')`, it said it couldn't find it. What connect-assets (or perhaps mincer) seems to do is strip the first directory from the assets. In order to reference your image, you need to specify it without the path e.g. `assetPath('logo.png')`.